# Entity framework with oracle "Extent1"."[COLUMN_NAME]": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

We are using `Oracle 12c` database with `Entity Framework 6.1`. We are using code first model to connect to Oracle database. 
Although the data is saved successfully while reading the data it gives and error on a column which has a foreign key dependency on another table.

The error says:

> "Extent1"."COLUMN_NAME": invalid identifier

I have checked the column name and the relationship between the table and the foreign key id.

Please suggest if anyone has faced the same issue.

regards,
A

Comment: Is `Extent1` the table you expect it to be looking at; and if so is its name really mixed-case in the data dictionary (i.e. created as a quoted identifier)? Have you specified the name as mixed-case somewhere in Entity Framework - and if so can you make is all uppercase? (All lowercase might also be OK).

Comment: The name of the column is all UPPERCASE in data dictionary (as in database). Surprisingly, this column name works fine for different query.

Comment: I'd expect it to be uppercase in the data dictionary; so where is Entity Framework getting the mixed-case name from?

Comment: Just noticed that whereever, EF generates a query with OUTER APPLY, this issue is encountered.